# Matplotlib: Closed frame

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I plot a figure with matplotlib, the frame around the (sub)plots are not closed rectangles but individual lines, leading to a plot looking like this as the surrounding frame corners (this is actually taken from somewhere else so the upper left corner looks like I would like to have it and the bottom left corner is what I got):

[image]

Is it somehow possible to get it right?

Comment: what are the `lines` properties set to in your `matplotlibrc` file?

Comment: I have no idea on how to check or change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2542) whch has been [fixed](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2544) on the master branch.  It will work properly in the next release.

Comment: Apply the patch locally or install from master

Comment: The bug seems to be missing option settings. Can I somehow set these options by myself in the python script? I have no permission to install something and no idea how to apply the patch locally.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  I would suggest opening a new question of the form 'I have this patch and a system-wide mpl installation I can't touch, how do I monkey-patch it?'